# Происхождение детских страшилок

Tags: фольклор

Во-первых, спасибо большое всем, кто принял участие в обсуждении темы о европейских сказках. А во-вторых, по ходу чтения у меня возник еще один вопрос: что-нибудь известно о происхождении той самой знаменитой детской страшилки о "черное-пречерной комнате"? Что-то мне не очень верится, что маленькие дети сочинили ее сами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень интересная подробная (с сылками) статья о детских страшилках в Википедии http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Детские_страшилки#section_6. Их причисляют к детскому фольклору. Авторские тоже есть. Например, Э. Успенского (хотя он тоже собрал сюжеты, литературно их обработал и издал).   Страшилки выделяют в отдельную группу, т.к. есть свои закономерности в постореннии сюжета.   О времени создания. В статье один из исследователей предположил, что страшилки получили широкое распространение в 60-70-е годы. Сейчас почти нет новых сюжетов. Хотя встречаются страшилки с современными деталями: смс, компьютер и т.п. 
В моем "лагерном" прошлом страшные истории были популярны. Особенно хороши ночью

Comment: Я в лагере не была ни разу, но страшилки мы с друзьями рассказывали обязательно. А потом, вечером, дружно боялись)))))

Comment: >А потом, вечером, дружно боялись)))))  
  
Вот в этом и есть "сакральный" смысл этих историй. Детям в определенном возрасте просто надо пережить весь спектр эмоций, в том числе и те, от которых детей дружно охраняют не вполне адекватные взрослые.

Comment: Да (это я про спектр эмоций)! Я (как и многие мои друзья) в подростковом возрасте любила ужастики (чем страшнее, тем лучше) и садистские стишки собирала. Тоже, кстати, детский фольклор :)))))  Сейчас ни ужасы, ни другие страшилки не люблю. И в жизни острых ощущений хватает. Старею, наверно...

Answer (score 0):

Детство  это  большой  временной  отрезок. Дети  вполне  способны  и  пересказать,  и  досочинить,  и  просто  сочинить.  Способности  и  таланты  проявляются  рано.

Answer (score 0):

Народное творчество. Вполне стандартный ответ. 
Старшие рассказывали младшим, младшие дополняли от себя...
Я, конечно, не про конкретную комнату, о которой, собсно, в детстве и не слышал. 
А вообще, о страшилках.

Я, кстати, помню одну такую в момент, видимо, её зарождения. В детском саду какая подменная воспитательница (не знаю как назвать, как сейчас понимаю - очень-очень молоденькая, возможно просто дочка воспитателки) рассказала нам, пятилеткам, сказочку про Барбулака. Сюжета всего я не помню, но он был весьма и весьма витиеватый и длинный. Про несчастную девушку, которую страшное-страшное существо Барбулак разлучило с любимым, довело обоих до смерти, а потом не оставило в покое и её душу. Потом мы её долго-долго пересказывали, дополняя и развивая сюжет. Девочку ту мы я больше не видели, возможно, кто-то из родителей таки нажаловался. Но меня более интересовал источник. Я его так и не нашёл.

Да я и сам был не дурак на такие придумки. Правда так страшно у меня никогда не получалось.

Comment: Детский  фольклор.